# Cannot load PouchDB in Adobe AIR

Tags: cordova, air, couchdb, phonegap-build, pouchdb

I've gotten PouchDB working in Chrome, Firefox, and Phone Gap, but I can't seem to get it to load in Adobe Air SDK.  I've tried versions 15 and 18 of the Adobe Air SDK, versions 3.5 and 3.6 of PouchDB, and adl and adt, and it doesn't even seem to instantiate the database objects at all, and certainly doesn't connect to Cloudant.

Do I need another library?  Or does it just not work in Adobe Air?

Here's the code I'm using and the alert that it creates.

Thanks!

Best,

Ben

===============================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Not Working</title>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="phoneincludes/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="phoneincludes/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script src="phoneincludes/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="phoneincludes/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
var db, remotedb;
var err = function(err) { alert(err) };
var changes = function(change) {
    $('body').append('<div>' + JSON.stringify(change.doc,null,4) + '</div>');
};

function dispatch(fn, args) {
    fn = (typeof fn == "function") ? fn : window[fn];
    return fn.apply(this, args || []);
}

$(function() {
    db = new PouchDB('todo');
    alert(JSON.stringify(db,null,4));
    remotedb = new PouchDB('https://user:pass@domain.cloudant.com/todo');
    db.replicate.from(remotedb, {retry: true, filter: 'app/nowhammies'})
        .on('complete', function() {
            db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function(docs) {
                for (var row in docs.rows) {
                    dispatch(changes, [docs.rows[row]]);
                }
            });
        }).on('error', err);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

=======================================

```
{
    "__opts": {},
    "prefix": "_pouch_",
    "_events": {},
    "taskqueue": {
        "isReady": false,
        "failed": {
            "message": "Adapter is missing",
            "code": 404,
            "line": 9,
            "expressionBeginOffset": 64839,
            "expressionEndOffset": 64891,
            "sourceId": 567532592,
            "sourceURL": "app:/phoneincludes/pouchdb.min.js"
        },
        "queue": []
    },
    "_db_name": "todo"
}
```

=======================================

Thanks for your answer, @JesseMonroy650.

Strangely, it doesn't seem that the deviceready event ever fires in Adobe Air.  For instance, this code outputs "zero" instead of "one".  Is Adobe Air just a completely different system than PhoneGap?  I'm really stumped why this would work in one but not the other...

=======================================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function onLoad() {
    $('#output').html('zero');
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    $('#output').html('one');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
<div id="output">hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK PouchDB has never supported Adobe Air.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST wait until **deviceready** before you use any services on the device. This include third-party libraries.

*deviceready* 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

*Handling PhoneGap Device Ready Event* 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CHR8vK3sIQ

*FYI – Cordova events must be run after deviceReady* 
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/07/15/fyi-cordova-events-must-be-run-after-deviceready

Jesse

Comment: @JesseMontroy650, it wouldn't let me add code to a comment, so I've answered in the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: AdobeAir and Phonegap ARE two (2) differnt products. I don't know much about Air, but Phonegap is an open source projects with lots of warts. But phonegap is one of the better open-source projects in the mobile space. MY guess is you want pouchDB. I would talk to that support group and not stackoverflow. Stack seems to be a last resort type of forum. Quality is relatively low, the entire system is somewhat of a hack. Then again the void is so large I see why it is popular. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pouchdb